# Easiest and most reliable way to center \chapter in the middle of a page (appendix)

Tags: chapters

I have a chapter called "Appendix" or "8 Appendix" with automatic numeration.

I want to position that one in the middle of the page without changing any font style, size etc.

It should be the only element on that page so that on the next pages the appendix content can be loaded.

Is there a simple way?

```
\chapter[Appendix]{\centering Appendix}
```

...does centre the chapter name horizontally but not vertically.

Comment: `\part*{Appendix}` should take care of it.

Comment: @John Kormylo With John Kormylo \part*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix} this works, but the page numbering resets from like page 37 to (i). How can I sustain the old numbering?

Comment: Please add some minimum compilable code from `\documentclass{...` to `\end{document}`